# MySQL IF(NULL != "", 1, 0) does not work as expected

Tags: mysql, sql

Can anyone explain this MySQL behavior? I thought that I understood boolean equations but MySQL might change all that.

```
SELECT IF(NULL = "", 1, 0);
SELECT IF(NULL != "", 1, 0);
-- Returns 0 in both cases
```

How can `NULL` not equal `""` and at the same time *not* not equal `""`?

Comment: NULL comparisons are always unknown, use IS NULL and IS NOT NULL instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comparing with `null` is neither `true` nor `false`. It is `unknown`.

So both statements are not `true`.

Always use the `IS` operator when comparing with `null`.

```
SELECT IF('' is not NULL, 1, 0);
```

In MySQL you can also use the *null-safe equal operator* `<=>`.

Comment: Is NULL is not "" accepted syntax? ANSI SQL says opposite order, i.e. "" is not NULL.